# onClick image link not working

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, onclick

I have a page with an onClick image link. When the image is clicked, it opens a pop-up window. On the pop-up window, I have another onClick image link that is supposed to open another pop-up window, but the link doesn’t work.  I am using the same code for both links. Why does the first link work but the second link doesn't?  The code I am using is:

```
<a href="#" onclick=
"window.open(’target URL','_blank','toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, copyhistory=0, menuBar=0, width=700, height=2700');return(false)">
<img height="110" src="%E2%80%9Cimage" width="180"></a>
```

Comment: Why ’ in window.open(’ there should be '

Comment: The code I am using is: <a href="#" onClick=“window.open(’target URL','_blank','toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, scrollbars=1, resizable=0, copyhistory=0, menuBar=0, width=400, height=700');return(false)"><img src=“image URL" height=60 width=60></a>   The code was edited by: Daniel Lisik

Comment: You posted exactly that same error. Retype first ’ in windows.open

Answer (score 0):

You had a `’` instead of `'`. Change:

```
window.open(’ta
```

to:

```
window.open('ta
```

Answer (score 0):

You should eliminate spaces between properties like `resizable=0, copyhistory=0` 
to be `resizable=0,copyhistory=0`. Also put it all in one line.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fNeeV/)

and the code:

```
<a  href="#" onclick = window.open("target_url","_blank","toolbar=0,location=0,directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=1,resizable=0,copyhistory=0,menuBar=0,width=700,height=2700");return(false)><img height="110" src="%E2%80%9Cimage" width="180"></a>
```

Comment: Hmm.. never heard of the spaces causing damage. Also, shouldn't the `onclick` attribute have the value inside of brackets?

Comment: you can see her in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2GPzs/ exactly the same code but now with spaces causes the problem - the window is not opening

Comment: Also your code is *not* the same, since you deleted the double quotes around the value of `onclick` attribute.

Comment: the difference is due to the fact that your code uses single brackets and my double.